# Garbage value while reading HTML body using C#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have below `HTML` file which contains content like below:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
...
........ company's Chief Financial Officer.   Now the.......
...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am reading the content of this file using:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
   String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
   stringBuilder.Append(line);
}
strFileContent = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

However it is returning string as:

*........ company�s Chief Financial Officer.���Now the.....*..

`HTML` files are in my local system.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file? Try specifying the encoding explicitly, otherwise `StreamReader` will default to `UTF8`.

Comment: @ Sriram, present encoding is charset=windows-1252. I think this is creating issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same encoding which was used to create the file. `StreamReader` assumes your encoding is `UTF8` by default and tries to decode the file using that, but your original encoding is `windows-1252`(as you said in comments). Trying to read with wrong encoding produces junk data for obvious reasons.

You should explicitly say what encoding the file is in. Here's how you do it.

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);//windows-1252
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath, encoding))
...
```

[Bonus reading](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

you must set Encoding in StreamReader like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
```